# Create a new list that contains the following values of certain words from another list

Tags: python, list

I need to create a new list that contains the following values ​​of certain words from another list.

I mean, I have a list:

```
 list = ['KAZES', 'CAR', 'MOTOR', 'TWO', 'SAINT', 'MOTOR', 'DOMAIN', 'BARCELONA']
```

And I want to create a list ONLY with the next values of the word 'MOTOR'. Like that:

```
 Motor = ['TWO','DOMAIN']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a one-line solution using a list comprehension:

```
motor = [lst[i+1] for i, word in enumerate(lst[:-1]) if word == 'MOTOR']
```

I renamed two of your variables: `list` to `lst` because `list` is a Python built-in, and `Motor` to `motor` because Python convention is lowercase variable names.

Comment: Just posted the same exact answre ;) +1 to you for being faster

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
def next_after (seq, key):
    it = iter(seq)
    while True:
        if next(it) == key:
            yield next(it)

result = list(next_after(my_orig_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

I rename your `list` to `ls` since `list` shadows a python builtin function. My approach is to loop over the current list and if we encounter the search word, we check to make sure we aren't at the end of the list, and then add the next item to the final list.

```
searchWord = 'MOTOR'

final = []
for i, e in enumerate(ls):
    if e == searchWord:
        if i + 1 < len(ls):
            final.append(ls[i + 1])
```

Hope I helped.